How long would it take for a global resurfacing event to turn a habitable world into a Venusian world?

Let’s imagine I have a warm, habitable, earth-like world that receives more stellar flux than Earth does, but thanks to having a higher albedo (due to a slow day length and more opaque atmosphere), its average temperature is around 35°C (hot but still habitable). The world is teeming with life, including a sapient humanoid species similar to humans.
This world has different tectonics than Earth does. Instead of plate tectonics, it has drip-and-plume tectonics, similar to Venus.
As life evolved in this world (and eventually sapience and civilization), volcanism reduced. This caused heat to build up in the mantle over several hundred million years until it burst through in a catastrophic global resurfacing. Think Siberian traps eruption but MANY times worse. It was so bad that it also threw the climate into a runaway greenhouse; drying out any remaining liquid water (by first turning it into lots of water vapor, trapping more heat; the water vapor then escapes into space through photodissociation), then spewing out $CO_2$ and turning the world into a Venusian-like planet. This is basically Doom of Valyria but on a planetary scale.
My question: How quickly could the resurfacing cataclysm occur so that all life will go extinct and turn the world Venusian?
Bonus related question if possible to answer: Can I have humanoids evolve unharmed prior to the resurfacing event (and with few warning signs for them) until all-of-a-sudden, everything dies?

How long? One hour, or one day, or one month, or one year, or one century, or one millennium, or one hundred millennia, or one million years, whatever you want. Nothing more precise can be said without actually constructing a mathematical model and doing the simulation. For example, here on Earth the Great Dying aka the Permian–Triassic extinction event, which killed 81% of marine species and 70% of terrestrial vertebrate species, lasted for some 60 thousand years. (Fun factoid: it's the only mass extinction to affect insects.)

@AlexP I’ll reword my question, hold on

The PT extinction with the Siberian Traps took around 60k years, but that's just how long the event itself took to play out. It was very slow by extinction standards. We're currently looking to have that impact in a mere 300 years without any planetary disaster to drive it.
People talk a lot about supvervolcano events, like the last Yellowstone eruption, but those don't even show up on the global extinction charts. They are a one-time dumping that kills a lot of plants, but the atmosphere clears up pretty quickly afterwards (by global extinction standards).
You don't get Siberian Traps behavior above supervolcanos because coal deposits above them have generally been burned away from previous events. But this is fiction, so you can do what you want.
The problem you're going to face is that greenhouse gasses aren't enough to create Venusian runaway greenhouse effect. You also must dissociate the water so that all of the hydrogen escapes. This means your magnetosphere has to collapse.
However, you could make the entire planet unlivable essentially overnight with a supervolcano event, blocking out all sunlight for a few years with volcanic ash. You can kill everything in the oceans in about 20 years by burning through a carbon sink, which will turn the oceans into carbonic acid (that's what we're working on now). That'll fill the air with greenhouse gasses, but also fill the sky with clouds, which have higher albedo.
Without dissociating radiation from magnetosphere collapse, however, you can't really keep it there, or make it go Venusian.

What I am going for is way worse than the eruption that made the Siberian traps. It’s like if the Siberian traps eruption happened all over the surface. Something like this: https://zenodo.org/records/1231347

@casualworldbuilder, This would be an extinction level event that would set evolution back hundreds of millions of years, but you wouldn't be converting water into hydrogen and oxygen in large amounts. You aren't going to get Venusian runaway warming without eliminating the hydrogen. It's like trying to get silt to stay suspended indefinitely in water by giving it an extra-good shaking.

I thought a runaway greenhouse can be triggered through reaching a critical temperature threshold. Once a sufficient temperature is reached, the oceans keep evaporating and start to boil. Water vapour then builds up in the atmosphere. This creates an irreversible process heating the planet so much that the magnetosphere will end up shutting down on its own (along with the ozone layer). I think this stage is called a moist greenhouse which happens just before the runaway greenhouse. Source: https://youtu.be/HqEd_VpHKLc?feature=shared

Welcome to the bleeding edge of climate science. There is a lot of back-and-forth regarding how water vapor and clouds effect heat absorption. Water vapor is a very strong greenhouse gas, but clouds are a major contributor to albedo. The video you referenced describes something beyond that, where water vapor becomes a significant portion of the atmosphere, increasing atmospheric density. The Earth doesn't get enough heat from the Sun to make that happen, but your planet might.

@casualworldbuilder, however, in doing so, you go so far afield of current conditions that you can write your own schedule. Pick the conditions you want based on the narrative you want to build. You don't need us for that.

The problem that I have with this scenario is energy: there isn't enough of it.  According to the worldbuildingpasta article that the OP linked, stagnant lid tectonics is a lower-energy tectonic state that occurs as the world cools from the heat of its creation.  Without some way to keep the asthenosphere hot, it's going to slowly cool, and the energy to cause a major resurfacing event just isn't there.
However, that isn't accounting for external influences.  There's a school of thought that Earth's moon is responsible for Earth's active plate tectonics, that Earth has plate tectonisc while Venus does not because of the presence of the Moon.
So, what if this drip-and-plume world acquired a moon through gravitational capture, perhaps related to planetary migration?  If another body of a sufficient mass migrated so as to enter the same orbit, this would increase tidal stresses on the drip-and-plume world, causing tidal heating.
If the rate at which energy accumulates in the asthenosphere was sufficiently low, life and sentience could concievably evolve.  The capture of the world's moon would have been so long ago that the native sentients would never have seen it.  For all that they knew, it had always been there, though maybe a few scientists may have concluded that it was acquired relatively recently, perhaps fifty to a hundred thousand years ago.  The rest probably wouldn't really care.  However, unlike Earth's moon, which is moving away, perhaps this moon is gradually moving closer... perhaps it is orbiting retrograde, and the energy of the world's rotation is slowly reducing the moon's distance.
However, the asthenosphere is gradually getting hotter.  Tidal stresses are causing the internal temperature to rise, and the temperature is now approaching a critical point where certain rocks are beginning to melt.  As the moon gets closer, this process will accelerate.  Volcanoes begin to erupt, just occasionally at first, but the average time between eruptions will decrease.  Then, perhaps the temperature rises enough, the lithosphere  becomes thin enough due to increasing temperature that as the asthenosphere expands, the lithosphere and crust begins to crack.  Over the course of a few thousand years, the crust splits, and dark rock from the planet's core wells up, spreading across the surface and increasing the albedo as the world begins to transition from drips and plumes to plate tectonics.
The local sentient life forms may have had tens of thousands of years of civilisation before the world reaches this point, then over the course of a thousand or so years, volcanism rises, lava flows, and there is runaway global warming... all because a moon was captured just as the sentient species was rising to sentience.

This is another good scenario. However didn’t Venus have a global resurfacing event on its own millions of years ago, without the presence of a moon? https://zenodo.org/records/1231347

@casualworldbuilder That doesn't mean that it happened all at once, or that the world was habitable before it happened.

I know Venus probably wasn’t habitable beforehand, but the reason I bring it up is largely to do with the debate surrounding the drip-and-plume tectonics of Venus and how the global resurfacing event there happened. Also, when Worldbuilding pasta’s author talked about drip-and-plume being less energic, I think he was comparing it to heat-pipe tectonics. It would still have a lot of heat for billions of years. I’m still not sure how a resurfacing event like I described couldn’t happen without a captured moon?

@casualworldbuilder My main point was that Venus' resurfacing didn't happen all at once.  If you want rapid resurfacing, you need to add energy.

I found this page: https://www.planetary.org/articles/the-venus-controversy which talks about a debate between the catastrophic hypothesis vs steady state hypothesis of Venus. Currently, more sources seem to favour a short, extremely violent resurfacing event.

@casualworldbuilder That's an interesting article.  However, it suggests catastrophic resurfacing over a 100,000 year time frame, and that as the core cools, capacity for that is lost.  That was pretty much my instinct, hence this answer.

To be fair, all I really need is for the resurfacing event bad enough to kickstart a runaway greenhouse that leads to the extinction of all life on the planet. I only need one event, not several.

@casualworldbuilder I don't think that you're going to get a runaway greenhouse effect without a significant decrease in albedo.  My guess is that you'd need around 20%+ of the surface to become significantly darker to get the effect you want.

The Siberian traps eruption (the one that caused the great dying) covered an area the size of Greenland and at some point it raised the temperature of Earth up to nearly 40°C (according to some estimates). Honestly I think anything significantly worse than that would be enough to make the oceans evaporate in a positive feedback loop, trapping heat until all the oceans are gone (and you get an extremely thick atmosphere with a VERY hot surface). This is the evaporation phase of a runaway greenhouse.
